# Lodash Typescript definition errors with gulp tsd

Tags: angularjs, typescript, lodash, tsd

My company recently updated to latest typescript definitions related to lodash library from DefinitelyTyped using `tsd` and suddenly ran into these typing error. If anyone could point out or help in this regard, we would be very thankful...

*We are using AngularJS with Typescript [Disclaimer]*

**Error**

```
error TS4063: Parameter 'lodash' of constructor from exported class has or is using private name '_'.

typings/lodash/lodash.d.ts(6497,19): error TS1005: '=' expected.
typings/lodash/lodash.d.ts(6497,23): error TS1005: '(' expected.
typings/lodash/lodash.d.ts(6498,19): error TS1005: '=' expected.
typings/lodash/lodash.d.ts(6498,27): error TS1005: '(' expected.
typings/lodash/lodash.d.ts(6499,19): error TS1005: '=' expected.
typings/lodash/lodash.d.ts(6499,31): error TS1005: '(' expected.
typings/lodash/lodash.d.ts(6500,19): error TS1005: '=' expected.
typings/lodash/lodash.d.ts(6500,35): error TS1005: '(' expected.
typings/lodash/lodash.d.ts(6501,19): error TS1005: '=' expected.
typings/lodash/lodash.d.ts(6501,39): error TS1005: '(' expected.
```

### Here is the screenshot.

[image: Lodash typings error]

Comment: What version of typescript are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line 6497 of *lodash.d.ts* [contains](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/lodash/lodash.d.ts#L6497) the following type alias:

```
type Function0<R> = () => R;
```

The problem, most likely, is that you don't use TypeScript 1.6 that [adds](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap) [generic type aliases](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1616). Unfortunately DefinitelyTyped is not versioned, so your best solution is to use TypeScript 1.6 (the latest stable version as of now).